# Postgresql update using CTE and priority

Tags: postgresql

I have a **employee leave balance** table as follows

| emp_code | leave_type | yearmonth | Balance | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PL | 202205 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | PL | 202205 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | PL | 202205 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |

and a **Attendance Table** as follows

| emp_code | date | yearmonth | Attendance | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 1 |  |

I just wanted to update the `attendance table` with the respective leave (based on the priority and availability) if the attendance field value is 0

For eg: employee 1 have 3 leave balance and 4 days absent

After the update, the records for emp_code 1 in attendance should be as follows

| emp_code | date | yearmonth | Attendance | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 0 | PL |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 0 | PL |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 0 | SL |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 | 202205 | 0 |  |

I know, we can do this through SP or function. But my company policy does not allow me to create SP or functions (I can update this via my backend code, but there are millions of records there to be updated so I am worried about the performance)

I wonder, is there any ways to achieve this in PG using CTE/Window function/any other means ?
Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4953

Pg version :12

Thanks

Comment: Enumerate according to the priority (window SUM(Balance) for employee leave balance table and ROW_NUMBER() for attendance table) and use this enumeration as additional joining condition.

Comment: @Akina can you share a sample code please

Comment: Provide your data sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina here is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_code ORDER BY priority) cum_sum
    FROM emp_leave_balance
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_code ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM attendance
)
SELECT cte2.emp_code, 
       cte2.date,
       cte2.yearmonth,
       cte2.attendance,
       cte1.leave_type
FROM cte2
LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte2.emp_code = cte1.emp_code
              AND cte2.rn <= cte1.cum_sum
              AND cte2.rn > cte1.cum_sum - cte1.balance
WHERE cte2.attendance = 0
ORDER BY emp_code, date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b35c63631a0808e9007d61bc502352a7